# How do I step through a method in an unmanaged DLL when loaded from a managed project? (Visual C++/C#)

Tags: c#, c++, unmanaged, dllimport, dllexport

I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution with 3 projects. The first is an unmanaged DLL project (C++) that I've written with a few DLL exports. The second project is a Managed wrapper for the first project (C# using DLLImport). The final project is a WPF application I'm using to test out the functionality of the first projects.

I'm using the first project by copying the DLL in a post-build step to the release/debug folder of the wrapper. However, this isn't enough to allow me to step through it in the debugger. I can't figure out how to reference the project properly so that I'm loading debug symbols for the unmanaged DLL. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [enabling unmanaged code debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdw0c6sf.aspx):

> To enable debugging of unmanaged code
>
> 1. With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu, click
>      Properties.
> 2. Click the Debug tab.
> 3. Select the Enable unmanaged code debugging check box.

Comment: Yep, that was all I needed! Thank you!